# Is there a way to get all values of variables in a python script?

Tags: python, parsing, python-2.7

If this question is out of scope, please suggest where I can move it.

I am having a lot of python (version 2.7) scripts, which are invoking each other. To get a view of which script
calls which, I have currently built a nice GUI tree that maps this.

The problem I have lies within parsing the files. The simplest example of a script invoking another script is calling:

```
os.system('another.py')
```

This is trivial to parse, just take what is inside the parenthesis. I have now come to evaluating variables.
My current way of evaluating variables works like this:

```
x = 'another'
dot = '.'
py = 'py'
os.system(x+dot+py) # Find three variables

listOfVars = getVarsBetweenParenthesis() # Pseudo code.

# Call getVarValue to find value for every variable, then add these together 

'''
    Finds the value of a variable.
'''
def getVarValue(data, variable, stop):
    match = ''
    for line in data:
        noString = line.replace(' ', '') # Remove spaces
        if variable+'=' in noString:
            match = line.replace(variable+'=', '').strip()
        if line == stop:
            break
    return match
```

Aside from being an ugly hack, this code has its disadvantages. When doing the
`Call getVarValue to find value for every variable, then add these together` not all variables get their desired value.
For instance:

```
x = os.getcwd() # Cannot be found by getVarValue
script = 'x.py'
os.system(x+script) # Find three variables
```

The problem is that I do not want to invoke these scripts (some scripts create/updates files), but rather parse them by value.
Since the python interpreter is able to parse scripts I figure that this must be possible.

I have already looked in to [tokenize](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tokenize.html), which gave me little help, and [abstract syntax trees](https://docs.python.org/release/2.7/library/ast.html).
However, both of these do not seem to be able to parse variables without running the file.

Is there a way (preferably pythonic) to retrieve a variable value without executing the script?

Comment: Think about what you are asking: If the value of a variable changes once the script is executed, what do you want to show? The initial value, or the calculated value?

Comment: I'm not sure, but have you tried monkeypatching `os.system`? Someithing like this: `os.system = lambda script_name: send_script_name_to_where_you_collect_them(script_name`.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: Hmm, good question! I would like to find all values, so that I can find all scripts that are being called.

Comment: @J0HN Didnt think of that, thanks :) If I would like to do that for more modules than os.system, I would have to monkeypatch all of those modules right?

Comment: Yes. Also, you might want to keep track of what you have patched an restore it to original values at some point.

Comment: @J0HN Ah yes. Otherwise parsing other scripts will probably yield interesting bugs. I will give it a try and see what I can find :)

Comment: I tried now, and the task is impossible without running the script. Imagine the following case: A script in subfolder x that has a main method, calls os.chdir(someFolder) where someFolder might be relative or absolute. It then calls os.system() with a script. If I have many scripts with the same name, I need to find exactly what the script is doing when it changes cwd. As this can be done differently with different scripts, finding all solutions will be both impractical and impossible! The only way to go is to launch the script in some kind of controlled environment, and find values.

Comment: See this link for a Python3 answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42875156

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified from this [Python3 Q&A,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42875156) here is an example of using the ast module to extract a variable.

It could be modified to extract all variables, but `ast.literal_eval` can only evaluate simple types.

```
def safe_eval_var_from_file(mod_path, variable, default=None, raise_exception=False):
    import ast
    ModuleType = type(ast)
    with open(mod_path, "r") as file_mod:
        data = file_mod.read()

    try:
        ast_data = ast.parse(data, filename=mod_path)
    except:
        if raise_exception:
            raise
        print("Syntax error 'ast.parse' can't read %r" % mod_path)
        import traceback
        traceback.print_exc()

    if ast_data:
        for body in ast_data.body:
            if body.__class__ == ast.Assign:
                if len(body.targets) == 1:
                    print(body.targets[0])
                    if getattr(body.targets[0], "id", "") == variable:
                        try:
                            return ast.literal_eval(body.value)
                        except:
                            if raise_exception:
                                raise
                            print("AST error parsing %r for %r" % (variable, mod_path))
                            import traceback
                            traceback.print_exc()
    return default

# example use
this_variable = {"Hello": 1.5, 'World': [1, 2, 3]}
that_variable = safe_eval_var_from_file(__file__, "this_variable")
print(this_variable)
print(that_variable)
```