# How to extract variables in a Python script without executing it?

Tags: python-3.x

In some cases its useful to read data from a Python script (which may be from an un-trusted source), and extract values from it.

Even though in most cases a format such as XML/JSON/YAML/TOML is better suited, there are times when its useful to do this.

How can variable names & values be extracted from a Python script without executing it?
*(assuming the values construction doesn't contain code-execution for their creation)*

Answer (score 5):

This can be done using Python's `ast` module:

This example function reads a single named variable from a file.

Of course this requires the variable can be evaluated using [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

```py
def safe_eval_var_from_file(mod_path, variable, default=None, *, raise_exception=False):
    import ast
    ModuleType = type(ast)
    with open(mod_path, "r", encoding='UTF-8') as file_mod:
        data = file_mod.read()

    try:
        ast_data = ast.parse(data, filename=mod_path)
    except Exception as ex:
        if raise_exception:
            raise
        print("AST error ({!r}), {!r}, {!r}".format(ex, mod_path))
        ast_data = None

    if ast_data is not None:
        for body in ast_data.body:
            if body.__class__ == ast.Assign:
                if len(body.targets) == 1:
                    if getattr(body.targets[0], "id", "") == variable:
                        try:
                            return ast.literal_eval(body.value)
                        except Exception as ex:
                            if raise_exception:
                                raise
                            print("AST error ({!r}) {!r} for {!r}".format(
                                ex, variable, mod_path,
                            ))
    return default


# Example use, read from ourself :)
that_variable = safe_eval_var_from_file(__file__, "this_variable")
this_variable = {"Hello": 1.5, b'World': [1, 2, 3], "this is": {'a set'}}
assert(this_variable == that_variable)
```